# Spark configurations not being updated

Tags: apache-spark, memory, pyspark

I am trying to update some default spark configurations. From the spark UI, in the **Executors** window, I can see that the memory assigned to each executor is **6GiB** as shown in the image below:

[image]

I am trying to update the `spark.driver.memory`, `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.executor.pyspark.memory` by using the following code:

```
import pyspark

cores = 8

# create spark session
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .master(f"local[{cores}]") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "10G") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "10G") \
    .config("spark.executor.pyspark.memory", "10G") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

By checking in the **Environment** window, it seems like all values were updated:

[image]

However, if I check again in the **Executors** window I can see that the *Storage Memory* column has not been updated. I'm not completely sure if the parameters are correctly being updated or if I am updating the correct parameters. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Op, it will helpful if you read some concepts of spark :`driver`, `executors`, `setting no of exectuor` `execution memory` `storage memory` . The way you are interpreting the UI is wrong. firstly you are looking at DRIVER not executor. And You are seeing Reserved storage memory 6GB , not total memory.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the following tutorial you will understand why **Storage Memory** is displaying less.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Memory-Management/ta-p/317794

Find the "**Understand the Memory Allocation using Spark UI**". Here clearly it is explained why **Storage Memory** will be less.

If you like it tutorial give kudos and accept the answer.